# How to connect to a server using OpenSSL and Delphi, not sure if I need a IOHandler such as IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1

Tags: delphi, tcp, tls1.2

How do I connect to a server using OpenSSL and Delphi?  I'm not sure if I need an IOHandler, such as `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`.

The server is not currently performing client authentication at the TLS level.  As such, client certificates are not required.  A standard X.509 v3 certificate signed by a third party CA (Certificate Authority) is being utilized by the server.

I have copied the OpenSSL DLLs to my application folder.

I can connect to the server without the use of the IOHandler.  I'm not sure if it's a secured connection or not.

Without the IOHandler, it connects just fine, but I don't know if it is securely connected.  Here is the code:

```
procedure TFrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  With IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do
  begin
    Destination := 'dev-eclaimsrx.relayhealth.com:18009';
    Host := 'dev-eclaimsrx.relayhealth.com';
    Port := 18009;
    SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  end;

  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
  IdTCPClient1.Host := 'dev-eclaimsrx.relayhealth.com';
  IdTCPClient1.Port := 18009;
  IdTCPClient1.Connect;
end;
```

Comment: Please show your actual code for connecting to a server. `TIdIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is an Indy component. Are you using Indy to connect to the server?

Comment: Just posted the actual code, it connects with out the handler, not sure if if securely connected.

Comment: You do not need to, and should not, set the IOHandler's `Destination`, `Host`, and `Port` properties.  That is handled by `Connect()` internally.

Answer (score 1):

It is secure only in that the data transfer is encrypted between the client and server and cannot be intercepted, but it is not fully secure because the client does not verify the server's identity.  To do that, you need to enable the `sslvrfPeer` flag in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode` property (and optionally the `sslvrfFailIfNoPeerCert` flag), and you should also check the server's certificate values in the `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.OnVerifyPeer` event.

Comment: Note that it is securely encrypted **ONLY IF** `TIdIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` is assigned to the `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler` property, and the `TIdIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.PassThrough` property is set to False.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I have checked all your suggestions.  I am still getting "Error connecting with SSL, EOF was observed that violates the protocol" Wondering if I am missing something?

Comment: @user734781 what OpenSSL version are you using? I had error you describe with old 1.0.0. With 1.0.1m it connected successfully